# How to set default field values when Django's reverse() is used for admin "add" page?

Tags: python, django

In Django I use:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("admin:article_article_add"))
```

And I can see admin's "Add" page.
Can I somehow set values for fields of my model in this case?
Maybe it's impossible or maybe I didn't find it.

I want to predefine some fields when I redirect to "Add new" page

Answer (score 1):

you could do it by passing some values in GET, but this wont work always(e.g. for datefields etc..), i would do it with custom [ModelAdmins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) with [get_form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
       form = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
       form.base_fields['your_field_name'].initial = 'abcd'
       return form
```

Comment: you should check out the ```get_chageform_initial_data(self, request)``` method instead when needing to set initial date/time fields.

Answer (score 0):

did you try simply adding it to a string?

`reverse("admin:...")+"&fieldname=value"`

you may need to use formating like this

`return HttpResponseRedirect('%s%s'%(reverse("..."), '&field=value'))`

depending on what your values are, you may need to also use a uri encoding routine (there are many ways to do this).